# Collator nodes are not working

Tags: polkadot, parachain, parachain-collator, relay-chain

[image: Screenshot]I recently got a parachain ie, 4058 via subport issues request form

When I was starting my parachain-collator-template with the following command

*./target/release/parachain-collator 

--bob 

--collator 

--force-authoring 

--chain rococo-local-parachain-2000-raw.json 

--base-path /tmp/parachain/bob 

--port 40334 

--ws-port 8845 

-- 

--execution wasm 

--chain rococo.json 

--port 30344 

--ws-port 9978*

[rococo.json](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CgM4qa81-xsWYOPVih3b3yiBuNPxmLRh/view?usp=sharing)

[rococo-local-parachain-2000-raw.json](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K_i5QLPi-n1-Z81sRJE9Ksozi2VBXKk_/view?usp=sharing)

It just shows logs of syncing peers

I'm not able to produce new blocks via collators

Can anyone help me? How can I able to solve this problem?

Comment: What Polkadot version of Cumulus are you using? Make sure you're using latest - which at time of writing this is `polkadot-v0.9.27`.

Comment: Has your collator completed syncing? Please include your collator logs in your post.

Comment: @Bruno I have added logs picture in post, kindly have a look

Comment: You probably want to change your `tokeySymbol` in your chain spec to something other than ROC if you're parachain has it's own native currency. You also want to change `name`, `id`, `protocolId`, and you're missing `"relay_chain": "rococo"`. Take a look at this example chain spec [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paritytech/cumulus/master/parachains/chain-specs/contracts-rococo.json)

Comment: Pavan, looks like it is still syncing.

Comment: @Bruno
May i know why its only showing syncing and how much time it takes to reach next steps

Answer (score 4):

The Parachain will not start producing blocks until you have reached the tip of the relay chain. Each Parachain block is build on a specific relay chain block and this currently requires that you always build on the latest block of the relay chain. In the future this will be relaxed a little bit, but the relay chain block will still be required to be near of the tip of relay chain.

So, you will need to wait for your collator to have finished syncing the relay chain to start producing blocks.

Comment: Oh I got now, thanks
Iam curious now when this relay chain logs will change

Comment: @bkchr how much time do you think it takes to syncing ? I have been running collator since 6 hours and still not finished syncing