# What after slot assigned?

Tags: parachain, substrate-parachain-template, rococo, substrate-node

We now assigned slots [here](https://github.com/paritytech/subport/issues/582#issuecomment-1667816235).

and I can see my paraId in `Network->Parachains->Overview` section.
I also started the collator node but not blocks are producing. this is log after running collator node,

[image]

[image]

What I am supposed to do now?

Comment: Did you tried the process locally and it worked: https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-parachain/connect-a-local-parachain/?

Comment: And if you are using custom keys, check you are adding them propertly: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5397/how-to-properly-set-session-keys-for-relay-and-parachain-with-custom-keys?rq=1

Comment: @AlexBean locally it worked fine, should I have to run local parachain even I am testing on rococo?

Comment: No. You don't need to run the local relay chain if you are connected to Rococo. But to discard that there are some problems with the configuration, you were able to connect your local parachain with a local relay chain like in the tutorials?

Comment: @AlexBean it was not easy at first but I got help to connect local parachain with local relay chain and I was successful to connect then only I request for slots in rococo.

Comment: now slots assigned and I am running collator node but no blocks are producing, I am blank how to processed further

Comment: Not producing blocks can be due to very diverse scenarios, is hard say one. I'll help you to debug it, try the following, If you try to execute an extrinsic, are you getting any error? Have you add custom keys for the collator (see the link shared above), how many collators are you running? Are you sure the wasm and genesis file are right? you can try the process with a local relay chain as in the tutorials

Comment: while execute an extrinsic, nothing happens it just loading. While creating `plain-parachain-chainspec.json` file [here](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-parachain/acquire-a-testnet-slot/#modify-the-chain-specification-file) in `step 5`, it says to `Add the public key for your account to the session keys section`, I replaced it with my rococo wallet public key `5EcKtQoUJAJc6Ekz3XNaR9LRsDWrqCMVnZNAa7N21JzuZL7e`. For collator I am running this command [here](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-parachain/acquire-a-testnet-slot/#start-the-collator-node) from tutorial.

Comment: [this is template code which I am using](https://github.com/ganesh1233456/xcav-praachain)

Comment: Fixed after the offboarding/onboarding?

Answer (score 1):

In the logs I can see the message it says is syncing.
See this old StackExchange question: [Collator nodes are not working](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4301/collator-nodes-are-not-working).

The Parachain will not start producing blocks until you have reached the tip of the relay chain. You will need to wait for your collator to have finished syncing the relay chain to start producing blocks.

Comment: ok how much time do you think it takes to syncing ?

Comment: Not sure to be honest it depends, let's wait until you don't see this Syncing message anymore

Comment: I have been trying to since 6 hours, but still not syncing, does it take more that this time or something is wrong?

Comment: you mean is still syncing?