# How to test parachain after slots acquired?

Tags: substrate-parachain-template, rococo, substrate-node, parachain-launch

I have acquired parachain in rococo test chain with parachain `4,285`.

[image]

After that I try to start the collator node using following command as shown in [`Acquire a testnet slots tutorial`](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-parachain/acquire-a-testnet-slot/#start-the-collator-node),

```
./target/release/parachain-template-node --collator \
  --chain raw-parachain-chainspec.json \
  --base-path ./tmp/parachain/pubs-demo \
  --port 50333 \
  --rpc-port 8855 \
  -- \
  --execution wasm \
  --chain rococo \
  --port 50343 \
  --rpc-port 9988
```

When I run the collator node in my terminal, then I get this logs,
[image]

But here parachain node doesn't peer with Rococo validator nodes to produce blocks. When I try to access custom endpoint of parachain using `ws://127.0.0.1:8855`, not able to access.

[image]

Someone guide me how to Test parachain after slot acquired?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What after slot assigned?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/9541/what-after-slot-assigned)

Answer (score 0):

It's evident that you're utilizing an endpoint labeled as `8855` within your search engine for your explorer, while concurrently employing a websocket (ws) port set at `9944` in your terminal. To ensure smooth access to your port, consider modifying the endpoint configuration within your search engine accordingly`(change to 8845 to 9944 in your search engine)`. This adjustment will allow you to seamlessly open the specified port and establish the desired connections.
Let me know if  it works.
or you can try this command and edit it as your relaychain port and path of your parachain and relay chain.

> ./target/release/parachain-template-node --alice --collator --force-authoring --chain raw-parachain-chainspec.json --base-path / --port 8855 --ws-port 9944 -- --execution wasm --chain ../peer-relay-chain/customSpecRaw.json --port 9988 --ws-port 9945 --bootnodes /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/30333/p2p/enter your relaychain local identity